# SQL Profiler SP_Count Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Would running a SQL Profiler in Microsoft SQL Server Management for SP_Counts on a live database cause noticeable performance issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, yes, [running Profiler at all is going to cause a noticeable performance hit](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events). In your case, specifically, it's impossible for us to tell what the impact will be - we don't know how busy your system is, what kind of load it's currently under, and what type of volume this trace will actually be capturing. This is something that you can test quite easily, though.

In general, you should use a server-side trace (or extended events) and avoiding collecting live data in Profiler. It's ok to configure your trace there, but many companies - for good reason - have an explicit policy forbidding the use of Profiler against production systems.

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to do a server-side trace like you suggested. I wanted to see if profiler would be low cost because it is easier to use instead of logging from all stored procedures.